# WebDriver: Suddenly my stable tests fails with "Other Element Would Receive Click"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a dusin automated UI end-to-end tests in WebDriver with C# on Chrome.  When I came back from vacation most of them stopped working with an error similar to each other - only the blocking element and the coordinates differ:

```
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (184, 685). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
(Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.82)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933  (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Nothing related to the tests code or the business code was changed when they stopped working.

The elements we're trying to click are alle visible and unblocked by other elements when I'm debugging the tests.

I've tried adding extra synchronization functionality that makes sure that the elements are clickable before trying to click, which doesn't deem the elements unclickable.

Any help in solving or working around this is much appreciated.

Comment: In the error message it states which element is receiving the click. It's likely a timing issue (some popup not dismissed fully, etc.) or a locator that is getting a new (and wrong) element. You'll have to do some more investigation into this on your own since we don't have access to the page.

Comment: UPDATE: I found out that we were forcing a spinner to be shown for 500 ms for debugging. The expected content now replaces the spinner as soon as it is loaded. Meanwhile, the size of the content area is animated causing the elements to move while trying to click them OR causing some other element to block the element we're trying to click. I will try to wait for the spinner to unload either with ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(locator) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If have tried all but never got success, Here is another solution provided by selenium to perform click using `IJavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
IWebElement yourElement = driver.FindElement...

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()",yourElement);
```

Hope it works..:)

Comment: I like this solution as it gets the job done. However, the element could actually be obscured. Perhaps checking if the element is clickable immediately before executing the script mitigate that.

Answer (score 1):

According to Selenium Release-Notes, an new NoSuchSessionException was introduced with the WebDriver v2.53.0
Java: Introducing NoSuchSessionException in the core API

This "missing" Session is making the Browser Unreachable.

BugTicket to the Chromium-Community, maintainig ChromeDriver, already exists:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396

I am facing Problem on both ff and chrome.This ain't a Browser problem but a core WebDriver bug.